# How to have multiple URLs in a let URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following statement in my frontend JavaScript

```
let totalURL = "http://total.40313993.qpc.hal.davecutting.uk";
```

I would like to add another URL to this, if the first one fails then use this URL. I have no idea how i would implement this in JavaScript any and all help is very welcome and appreciated.

Where totalURL is used:

```
function getTotal()
{
    input_text = document.getElementById('input-text').value + '-getTotal'
    if (input_text == '')
        return;
    else
    {
        input_text_edited = '';
        lines = input_text.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if(i != (lines.length-1)){
              input_text_edited += lines[i] + "newline";
            }
            else {
              input_text_edited += lines[i];
            }
        }

        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var j = JSON.parse(this.response);
                total_marks = j['total_marks'];
                displayTotal();
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET",totalURL+"?input_text="+input_text_edited);
        xhttp.send();

        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if it fails"?

Comment: its an ingress controller so if it was down for whatever reason.

Comment: what if the second one fails too?

Comment: That would be a problem. i guess you could look at it as a backup URL

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://lostsource.com/2012/12/01/detect-third-party-site-status-javascript.html

Comment: @NovaBrownie An "ingress controller" for what, exactly? And **where** is this JS code running? (in NodeJS? In WScript/CScript? In a browser? A browser extension?)

Comment: You'll need to show us the code where `totalURL` is used. The assignment statement you posted will never fail.

Comment: I added in the code where totalURL is used, the code is running in a browser and deployed to a private cloud.

Comment: @NovaBrownie "private cloud" is somewhat of an oxymoronic term.